# Bit shift using instruction add and nor in LC-2K

Tags: c

I'm trying to do logical shift right and logical shift left by just using LC-2K instructions only! In ARM ISA, assembly language, there are LSR and LSL for writing bit shifting in assembly language but LC-2K does not have such options.

The only options that's available in LC-2K are:
Lw, sw, beq, jalr, add, nor, noop, halt.

I can't seem to find a way to do any bit shifting by just using these few instructions possible in LC-2K assembly language.

Please give me some advices. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `add x,x` (ie multiply by two) should left shift `x` unless there's some overflow checking going on in the instruction.

Comment: Why is this tagged C?  The 'options' you give are not relevant to C per se; they might be relevant to a C compiler writer, but there is nothing to indicate that's what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift left 1 by adding a register to itself. You can shift left by more than one using a loop.

Right shift can be done with a loop that copies all of the bits except the bottom one to a scratch register, then copies the scratch register back to the source. I'm not familiar with LC-2K, but `nor` should be enough to let you mask off bits, `beq` will let you test whether the masked bit is set, and `add` will let you copy the bit to the destination register as well as shifting the working bit one left before looping. The easiest way I can think of uses two counters, one starting at 1 (for writing) and the other starting at 2 (for reading). There's probably other ways to do it, but that one occurs to me.

Comment: Can you go step by step on how you would right shift by using nor and add?

Comment: @TNT_42 I could, but I think at that point I would be doing your homework for you :)